# Pass a value from Parent to Child (Open) window

Tags: javascript

How to pass value from parent to child window field.
I use window.open("www.google.com");

after popwindow is opened i need to pass/set search value typed in parent window to child window(www.google.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a reference using the window.open() method:

```
var childWin = window.open("www.google.com" <etc.>);
```

Then treat childWin as a whole other window. For example,

```
childWin.document.getElementById('searchField')
```

will give you a reference to an element with ID of "searchField". Etc. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Note that you can also access variables defined in the newly opened window as well.

var childwin = window.open('....');
childwin.variable = 'somevalue';

If the variable was predefined, it will contain the new value, if it was not defined, it will now contain the value you set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a page or window with sending data POST or GET method you can use a code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",  // or post method, your choice
    url: yourFileForInclude.php, // any url in same origin
    data: data,  // data if you need send some data to page
    success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg); // for checking
                window.open('about:blank').document.body.innerHTML = msg;  // you can change  about:blank  to an url.
               }
});
```