# JavaScript that passes values between windows not working in Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have seen the other similar questions, but I still do not seem to get it right I got this JavaScript on my ASPX Page, however it works in IE and chrome but not Firefox. I have also tried FireBug plugin, but it does not seem to help.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function PassValues() {
                window.opener.document.forms(0).submit();
                self.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
From SO itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678133/pass-a-value-from-parent-to-child-open-window
```

Set a reference using the window.open() method:

```
var childWin = window.open("www.google.com" <etc.>);

Then treat childWin as a whole other window. For example,

childWin.document.getElementById('searchField')
```

will give you a reference to an element with ID of "searchField". Etc. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is using document.forms as a callable object.  Per spec, it's not.  Try `window.opener.document.forms[0].submit()`.