# Add content to a new open window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know how to solve this issue, I've trying reading many post but no one answer to it.

I need to open a new window with a page already coded (inside the same domain) and add some content.

The problem is that if I use `OpenWindow.write()` the page is not loaded yet or it overrides everything and only the code added through write appears.

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('mypage.html','_blank','width=335,height=330,resizable=1');
OpenWindow.document.write(output);
```

`output` is the code I need to append.

I need it to work at least on Firefox, IE and GC.

It is not a problem if I need to use JQuery.

Comment: I had tried as well:         OpenWindow.addEventListener("onload", function () {  
          OpenWindow.content.body.innerHTML = "<div>hello world</div>";  
        }, true);

Comment: When you call the function in the child window, you can not pass anything in the function arguments. You must just call childWin.function_name(). If you call childWin.function_name(output), it won't work. For passing data from parent to child, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678133/pass-a-value-from-parent-to-child-open-window

Answer (score 28, accepted):

in `parent`.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var output = "data";
        var OpenWindow = window.open("child.html", "mywin", '');
        OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output; // dataFromParent is a variable in child.html
        OpenWindow.init();
    });
</script>
```

in `child.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFromParent;    
    function init() {
        document.write(dataFromParent);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How to pass jquery variable/elemnts to child page from parent? @ray-cheng

Comment: How secure is this? You're not passing the data via the URL, but could there be an interception somewhere?

Comment: it gives undefined function init() on OpenWindow. Google Chrome

Answer (score 55):

When You want to open new tab/window (depends on Your browser configuration defaults):

```
output = 'Hello, World!';
window.open().document.write(output);
```

When output is an `Object` and You want get JSON, for example (also can generate any type of document, even image encoded in Base64)

```
output = ({a:1,b:'2'});
window.open('data:application/json;' + (window.btoa?'base64,'+btoa(JSON.stringify(output)):JSON.stringify(output)));
```

> **Update**
>
> Google Chrome (60.0.3112.90) block this code:
>
> `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:application/json;base64,eyJhIjoxLCJiIjoiMiJ9`

When You want to append some data to existing page

```
output = '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
window.open('output.html').document.body.innerHTML += output;

output = 'Hello, World!';
window.open('about:blank').document.body.innerText += output;
```

Comment: My popup got blocked by chrome, then `document` didn't work because `window.open` was undefined. So make sure your popup is a direct result of a user action. For more read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602964/how-do-i-prevent-google-chrome-from-blocking-my-popup

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you can try

- Write a function say init() inside mypage.html that do the html thing ( append or what ever)
- instead of `OpenWindow.document.write(output);` call `OpenWindow.init()` when the dom is ready

So the parent window will have

```
    OpenWindow.onload = function(){
       OpenWindow.init('test');
    }
```

and in the child

```
    function init(txt){
        $('#test').text(txt);
    }
```

Comment: I get "OpenWindow.init is not a function" error and I had defined the function: <script>
function init(code)
{
 $('#dummy').html(code);
}</script>

Comment: OpenWindow.init();
Is never executed :( Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

When you call `document.write` after a page has loaded it will eliminate all content and replace it with the parameter you provide.  Instead use DOM methods to add content, for example:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('mypage.html','_blank','width=335,height=330,resizable=1');
var text = document.createTextNode('hi');
OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(text);
```

If you want to use jQuery you get some better APIs to deal with.  For example:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('mypage.html','_blank','width=335,height=330,resizable=1');
$(OpenWindow.document.body).append('<p>hi</p>');
```

If you need the code to run after the new window's DOM is ready try:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('mypage.html','_blank','width=335,height=330,resizable=1');
$(OpenWindow.document.body).ready(function() {
    $(OpenWindow.document.body).append('<p>hi</p>');
});
```

Comment: It is not working, if I do it whilst debuging, the new window has time to load and the the "hi" is added, working everything fine, but in a normal situation, "hi" appears first, then the page is loaded overriding everthing :S Thanks for the help

Comment: I edited my answer to wrap the code in a $(document).ready block.  Try that.

Comment: This didn't work for me, what did work was- $(printWindow).on('load', function () { $(printWindow.document.body).find('#page-content').html(printContent); });

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a page or window with sending data POST or GET method you can use a code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",  // or post method, your choice
    url: yourFileForInclude.php, // any url in same origin
    data: data,  // data if you need send some data to page
    success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg); // for checking
                window.open('about:blank').document.body.innerHTML = msg;  
               }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

it is even more simple!

Just put the code below in between the `<head> </head>` of your code and all of your links will open in a new window:

```
<base target="_blank">
```