# How to add DOCTYPE to new JavaScript-generated window?

Tags: javascript, html, doctype, window.open

I'm generating new a window with JavaScript using `window.open` and putting some content in it.

How can i declare the `<!DOCTYPE>`?

Comment: document.doctype but DocumentType objects cannot be created dynamically in DOM Level 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

window.open just opens a new browser instance. It's the page's responsability, inside the popup, to declare its doctype.

**Edit**

Actually, I found this, but this example will only work if you're planning on overwriting the content of the newly opened window.

```
function openWin(){
    var winTitle='blah';
    var winBg='#FF0000';
    var newWin=window.open('', '', 'height=130, width=160');
    newWin.document.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head><title>'+winTitle+'</title></head>');
    newWin.document.write('<body bgColor="'+winBg+'"><img src="images/picture.jpg" border=0></body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `window.open` alone for this but it seems you can do this with a little more coding.

Check out this similar question. I think you could easily adapt it to do what you're asking.

[Add Content to new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)