# How to add a JS to html file opened via window.open method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the jquery code I am using to add a script file to a link opened via `document.open` method but it is not adding to the `url`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        var myid = $(this).attr('id');
        var url = "http://mysite.com/"+ myid +"/index.html";
        window.open(url,"_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");

        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "http://mysite.com/apiwrapper.js";
        $("head").append(s);
    })
})
```

I need to add `http://mysite.com/apiwrapper.js` to my `url` i.e. opened via `window.open` method

Comment: @Gautam3164 I tried this but not working :( actually I cannot add this in index.html page as it refers to the Users..so have to dynamically add this

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window