# Can Dart manipulate HTML elements in other windows?

Tags: javascript, html, dart, dart-html

So I have a Dart app embedded in a page and it opens another window that has a preexisting page with just HTML/JS. I was trying to get info into the page and display it from inside Dart, roughly like so:

```dart
    var div = querySelector("#div_id");
    div.text = "my message";
```

I tried different variations of that with different kinds of elements, but no luck.

Eventually, I just wrote display code in JS on the child window HTML and I passed the information in using a query string.

So my question is: can Dart manipulate another page if that page doesn't have dart.js and other stuff embedded in it? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dart, but if you can get a reference (in the compiled Javascript) to the window handle that was opened, you can reference that window's `document` object like so: `[window reference] .document.querySelector(...)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window

Answer (score 1):

If you create the new Window using the window.open() method then you get back a WindowBase object. You can dig into the new window's DOM using this reference.  For more information see https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Window#id_open