# How can I convert the result of a Javascript function into a page with only a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I need to load a url and have the only text on this page be a JSON string.

As an example I built a simple function to get the day of the week: `getDayOfWeek()`. My actual function is much more complex, and cannot easily be converted to another language.

But I cannot simply load this into the DOM. I need the **only** text on the page to be the JSON object.

For example:

http://example.com/what_day_is_it `// needs to return: { "day": "Friday" }`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7b49Lorw/

HTML:

```
<span id="day"></span>
```

JS:

```
function getDayOfWeek() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.getDay();
  var gsDayNames = new Array(
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
  );
  return gsDayNames[d.getDay()];
}
$('#day').text(getDayOfWeek());
```

Assuming I use PHP for the server side, how can I use PHP to evaluate the result of a JS function and return the JSON string?

Comment: Do you mean seralizing getDayOfWeek to JSON?

Comment: I need to be able to have another app call this web page: http://example.com/what_day_is_it and have the only text on that page be `{ "day" : "Friday" }`

Comment: I don't understand the issue at all but I'll try to address it with an incoming answer. Tell me if I got your issue rightly

Comment: Are you trying to create a rest service that returns current day name?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window

Comment: You can't do it using a HTML page and JavaScript. You will need some backend scripting like PHP.  Otherwise when a app sends a request to this url, the JavaScript won't execute.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't see you wanted to send it from the server. I thought you had it done already...

Comment: I'm fine using PHP to render the page. I just need help figuring that out.

Comment: @Ryan If that function is really difficult to convert to another language,you could have a look at [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/) .

Comment: Your JavaScript code is client side, so whatever calls your http://example.com/what_day_is_it URL will have to evaluate the code. If you want to run that code server side, you have to have a server with a server side installed JS engine. Alternatively, convert the code to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you included a PHP tag with your question (even though you didn't mention it):

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array('day' => date('l')));
```

***edit:***
Since we can only guess at what you're actually trying to do, and since you feel the difficulty of translating your 1000+ line JS function to some other language isn't worth it, why don't you just wrap the output of your function with something like:

```
JSON.stringify({ "day": <YourFunctionThatReturnsTheDay> });
```

and display it when the DOM is ready?  This would be assuming that whatever client that calls your page has the ability to parse and run Javascript.

Comment: Right, but my actual function is 1000 lines or so of javascript to calculate a simple string. Not easily converted into PHP. Though I'm open to using PHP if necessary to fetch and build the JSON string without any html.

Answer (score 0):

In php, you can generate code based on some arguments. For example you can have a paramter in you GET request, like: **http://example.com/what_day_is_it?onlyJSON=true**

And then in your code, wrap the visual part in

```
<!-- Your JSON print goes here -->
<?php if ($_GET['onlyJSON']){ ?>
<span id="day-of-week">

</span>

<!-- Your HTML code without parameter goes here-->
<?php } else {  ?>

<span> MY BIG PAGE </span>

<? } ?>
```

and your javascript will be that:

```
function getDayOfWeek() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.getDay();
    var gsDayNames = new Array(
      'Sunday',
      'Monday',
      'Tuesday',
      'Wednesday',
      'Thursday',
      'Friday',
      'Saturday'
    );
    return gsDayNames[d.getDay()];
}
$('#day').text(getDayOfWeek());
$('#day-of-week').html(JSON.stringify({day: getDayOfWeek()}));
```

That will make the page display only your JSON. From the **text** perspective it will be that. However, the page itself (its source) will not contain only that json. It will have HTML code + Javascript that processes it. To have a function in JS you need it to be a part of the Page.

Comment: I need to call this from another app that is expecting a pure JSON object. Think of it like a simple API call.

Comment: That's what I thought. In this case you need a server to generate JSON instead of HTML web-page with JS function. So you have 2 options. First is to rewrite the funciton in PHP. If you don't want to go away from JS, change your server from php to NodeJS. It's javascript and you can Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V 90% of your code in your server logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could install v8js (a PHP extension which allows the interpretation of Javascript code inside PHP). This guide covers installing and get started with v8js:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/running-javascript-inside-php