# Displaying load message in popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am redirecting my customer to new site using `window.open()`. I wanted to display some message or image before that site is loaded.

Here is my code.

```
 <input class="btn add-to-cart-btn" onclick="two();" 
            type="button" value="More Info At {{ product.vendor }}"/>
```

JavaScript code :

```
<script>

   function two()
    {

        window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');   trackOutboundLink('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}'); }

     alert("please wait your page is loading ");

       var trackOutboundLink = function(url) { ga('send', 'event', 'outgoing', 'click', url, { 'transport': 'beacon' });

}

</script>
```

Here `{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}` is a dynamic URL. The test alert message is displaying in same page.

any help ?

Comment: Do you want to display message in new window?

Answer (score 2):

Let's add a variable:

```
var newWin = window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');
newWin.alert('Message');
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want alert, just write message then try this:

```
newWin.document.write('Message');
```

`newWin` is a `window` object, so you can use it as is.

You can found more details here: [Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)

Comment: cool. its working fine . rather than alert  how can display the text ?

Comment: What do you mean display the text? What text? Where? You can use the `newWin` as a `window` object.

Comment: i don't want to display the alert . i want to display plain html text or CSS loaders or some image

Comment: see my edited answer. But your question was about the `alert`.

Comment: only message is appearing in new window . page is not loading

Answer (score 0):

The function `two()` you are calling is being executed from your page1(suppose) and you are opening page2(suppose) in new window. Your function is called by page1 so the alert will be shown in the same page. So either you should have a reference to the new window opened and then trigger an alert like

```
var NewWindow = window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');
NewWindow .alert('please wait your page is loading');
```

But this is not a good solution because javascript alert is a blocking function your JavaScript stops executing until they return so if there is some part of page that is dependent on javascript wont be loaded unless you close the popup.
What i would suggest is: there are lot of CSS loaders available on the net you just need to google out a bit. Use that in your page which will be shown to the user until all the data is populated or the page has finished loading. Something like have a modal div and make it visible and once the page finishes loading hide that div. Here is a demo for you which you can use as reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#one").html("finished loading");
    $("#cssload-contain").hide();
  },2000)
});
```

```css
#allthethings {
  width: 20%    ;
  height: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  top:35%;
  position:fixed;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
}

#cssload-contain {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.50);
    z-index: 1000;
}



.cssload-preloader {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 z-index: 10;
}

.cssload-preloader > .cssload-preloader-box {
 position: absolute;
 height: 29px;
 top: 50%;
    width:500px;
 margin: -15px 0 0 -146px;
 perspective: 195px;
  -o-perspective: 195px;
  -ms-perspective: 195px;
  -webkit-perspective: 195px;
  -moz-perspective: 195px;
}
.cssload-preloader .cssload-preloader-box > div {
 position: relative;
 width: 29px;
 height: 29px;
 background: rgb(204,204,204);
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 29px;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 19px;
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssload-contain">
        <div id="allthethings">
            <div class="cssload-preloader">
                <div class="cssload-preloader-box">
                    <div>L</div>
                    <div>o</div>
                    <div>a</div>
                    <div>d</div>
                    <div>i</div>
                    <div>n</div>
                    <div>g</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <label id="one"></label>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t1op5fk/)

Comment: how to call div here ? (var NewWindow = window.open('{{ product.metafields.google.custom_label_0 }}');
NewWindow .alert('please wait your page is loading');)

Comment: u dont need to call it it is already present on the page or just put it in your page that you will be opening in the new window. you just need to handle hiding it when you your data loading or page loading is finished.

Comment: its loading in same page .

Comment: you have two pages page1 and page2 this div you keep in page2 along with styling and script to hide it all should be kept in page2 because there is where you want to show this. Page1 is just a page which will help you to navigate you to page2.

Comment: i have only one page . i am just redirecting my customer to page 2 . i don't have any access for page2

Comment: ok so for this what you can do is create a new page and inside that keep this loading div. And also add one iframe to it load you page2 in that iframe instead of loading it directly. i.e in page2 have an iframe and in that load you required page and then add this to your page2 $('#the_iframe').load(function(){
     $("#cssload-contain").hide();
});
Where the_iframe is the id of the iframe. this hide your loading text when the page in frame completes loading. this is the only way because you can not handle pages out of your application.

Comment: http://codepen.io/manishjanky/pen/eZbJXv here is demo for what i m suggestinng you to do. Try this out.