# Display new text input

Tags: javascript, html

I got a question regarding my code. 
I got this function which opens a new window and creates a text input.
Now I am trying to display the new entered text in the new window but unfortunately it does not work..
Thank you very much in advance

Text:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="myAlert()">


<script>

    function myAlert()

    {

    var NewWindow= window.open();
    var nameValue = document.getElementById("vname").value;   
    NewWindow.document.write(nameValue);

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Send");

    NewWindow.document.body.appendChild(input);
    btn.appendChild(t);  
    NewWindow.document.body.appendChild(btn);


    }


</script>
```

Comment: **java != javascript**

Comment: java tag removed, javascript question tag added. Please understand that these are two completely different programming languages, about as closely related as ham is to hamburger, that if you mis-tag your question you will not get the right experts in to review it, and that this may hurt your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: Oke sorry won't happen again!

Comment: Is this your fullcode? Try creating a fiddle with your code until now in jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any input tag with `id` `vanme` . So the line,

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("vname").value;
```

will definitely throw an error. Rightclick>Inspect Element > Console and see the error.

The code should work fine if you set an `input` tag with id `vname` .

Comment: Even I thought the same. But it worked for me when I run the code with `var nameValue` initialized to some random value.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I guess he really missed the `input` with the `vname` id

Comment: Yes i posted just the function! Yeah thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
output = 'Hello, World!';
window.open().document.write(output);
```

link:-[Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)