# Open html5 <video> tag content (including video!) in new window

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am interested in opening a video in a new window/tab using the  tag, as I'm having intermittent issues with IE not being able to open linked .mp4 files. I have tried to cobble something in javascript together from other answers with my very flawed understanding, but I just can't make it work. Basically, I have videos, I want to be able to use this same code to reference them separately each time with a different link/button/picture and open them in a new window.

Here's my Attempt 1:

```js
<script>
function nWin () {
    var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=780,     height=200, top="+(screen.height-400)+", left="+(screen.width-840));
    win.document.body.innerHTML = "<html><body><video width="90% height="90%" controls><source src='myvideo.mp4' type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></body></html>"; 
} 
</script>
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="nWin()">Open</a>
```

Here's my Attempt 2:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#popup').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var w = window.open('about:blank', 'MyWindow', 'width=400,height=400');
        w.document.write('<html><body><video width="90% height="90%" controls><source src='myvideo.mp4' type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video></body></html>');
        w.document.close();  
      })
    });
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

  <a id="popup" href="">Open me</a>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe it is not possible to do this? Maybe I am missing something fundamental about functions. I thank you very sincerely in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)

Comment: New window or a modal? Like a popup window, but you are basically still on the same page.

Comment: Hi Natanel, I just took a look at that answer and I'm not sure how to make that work in this context--would I need to re-write code completely and have two different .html files that I save, upload, and then call? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Zer00ne, best case would be a new window, as we want the video to be watchable while people are looking at stuff in the original window. We are in a limited situation, too, as we are working with a Content Management System and therefore have just a "body" HTML-enabled window to work with.

Comment: @user2697568 Please take a look in my solution and let me know if this solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think this can solve your problem:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="open_in_new_window('html_contents', 'MyTitle', 'location=1,status=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,resizeable=1,width=500,height=250');">Open New Window</a>
<div id="html_contents" data-new-window> <!-- data-new-window is important -->
    <video controls style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
        <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-new-window] {
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function open_in_new_window(id, new_page_title, features) {
    var new_window;

    if(features !== undefined && features !== '') {
    new_window = window.open('', '_blank', features);
    }
    else {
        new_window = window.open('', '_blank');
    }

    var html_contents = document.getElementById(id);
    if(html_contents !== null) {
        new_window.document.write('<!doctype html><html><head><title>' + new_page_title + '</title><meta charset="UTF-8" /></head><body>' + html_contents.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

`#html_contents` stores the new page contents (`<video>`), to make it easier for you (instead of writing the entire page in javascript). The function needs the parameter `features` to define the new window (like in the `window.open()` function). you just need to call this function, and if the features are defined, it will be opened in a new window. if not, it'll be opened in a new tab (or any other way that defined by the browser).

CSS will hide `#html_contents` in the main window who calls this function.

[Original Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/kagobelago/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

I hope it will be helpful

Comment: This is absolutely helpful, you are amazing, but it isn't working for me, as I left out some info in my original question--there will be multiple videos on the same site, and I need to be able to add the code for each video (with a separate link for each) to the separate HTML-enabled "body" fields (content management system)  and have each of the videos load from the different links on the same page. I unfortunately can't put the CSS or Javascript into the overarching page.

Comment: @user2697568 You can make it for multiple windows and elements if you want - i'll edit my code and show you how to do it. but what do you mean by "it isn't working for me"?

Comment: That is all I mean--it is working, just didn't work for my situation because I needed it for multiple videos/multiple links on the same page. You are my superhero!!

Comment: @user2697568 [Is that what you tried to do](http://jsbin.com/pesurawofe/edit?html,css,js,output)? (code updated here too)

Comment: About inserting css (and javascript) to the new page: you can, but it's a little bit complicated - just insert it through the javascript code. you can make a parameter which can be called "css" and then insert there the stylesheet. e.g.: `your_function(css)` and in the function: `...<style>' + css + '</style>...`. Don't forget to escape characters while you're inserting html tags to your javascript: `"<div class=\"class\">"` and NOT `"<div class="class">`

Comment: Update: [Try it with CSS & JavaScript](http://jsbin.com/bimelejuxu/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thank you so much @natanel97, that was exactly perfect, and I learned a lot in the process, too. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! it will be very appreciated if you'll accept this answer. thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks again so much for your help, @natanelg97! If I wanted the videos to each open in the SAME window, would it be ridiculously complicated? That is, if I click on a different link, it will simply open that next video in the SAME window? Thank you!