# Open image in new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, imageurl

I want to open an image in a new tab.
I am using the below given code

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

My **image url** is "**data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB28AAATdCAYAAABosx2OAAAgAElE.....**".
Its working fine in firefox,but in chrome it just open a new blank tab. I tried with some other urls like 'http://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://www.google.com". Its woking fine in both chrome and firefox.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

[Deprecations and Removals in Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/chrome-58-deprecations#remove_content-initiated_top_frame_navigations_to_data_urls)

> **Remove content-initiated top frame navigations to data URLs**
>
> Because of their unfamiliarity to non-technical browser users, we're
>   increasingly seeing the `data:` scheme being used in spoofing and
>   phishing attacks. To prevent this, we're blocking web pages from
>   loading `data:` URLs in the top frame. This applies to `<a>` tags,
>   `window.open`, `window.location` and similar mechanisms. The `data:` scheme
>   will still work for resources loaded below by a page.
>
> *This feature will be **removed in Chrome 60***.

Comment: Is there any alternatives?

Comment: @Anna create a new HTML document to show in the popup on-the-fly (document.write), and have that contain an img element with the src attribute set to your data URI ...?

Comment: @Anna [Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="data:image/png;base64,..." download="abrakadabra_iLoveCats.jpg">download id</a>` – add "download=" attribute