# Access an element in a newly opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open an html file with JavaScript and write some data into some of its elements. I tried the following:

```
var info_window = window.open('info_print.html')
info_window.document.getElementById('new_info').innerHTML = data;
```

But I get this error while I have the `#new_info` element:

```
cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

what should I do?
I checked the commented question but it was not as my question.

Comment: Looks like there's no element with `id` equal to `new_info` in the new window. You're probably either searching for the wrong element or (more likely) not waiting enough time for the window to load the element you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add content to a new open window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window)

Comment: @richflow Not really a duplicate of that! The other question is asking for a totally different thing, and the suggested answers don't take into consideration the loading time of the window, since the other question's OP didn't need to. This is a totally different situation!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli my bad! please let me know what I should do to correct this.

Comment: @richflow well you can retract the close vote if you want, just click on "close" again and a menu will pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `info_print.html` actually contains the element you're looking for, then you need to wait for the Window to load it before accessing it.

Here's a simple solution using the `onload` event:

```
var info_window = window.open('info_print.html');

info_window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    info_window.document.getElementById('new_info').innerHTML = data;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created one [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tozx3bpy/2/) where it is working fine.
can you please check if your html file contains new_info element or not or if you are getting any errors in console.

below is my fiddle code.

```
var w = window.open('', "", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
//assuming html as your info_print.html file which contains new_info element
var html = '<div id="new_info"></div>';
w.document.body.innerHTML = html;
w.document.getElementById("new_info").innerHTML="test content";
```