Is it possible to get the HTML content of a web page which were opened through window.open method
Here is a demonstration of my doubt
I couldn't see any log on either of the windows and div "content-display" never changed


async function navigate() {
  const myWindow = window.open("https://www.example.com", "", "width=100,height=100");

  myWindow.onload = function() {
    const innerContent = myWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    displayContent(innerContent);
  };
}

function displayContent(content) {
  console.log(content)
  const contentDisplay = document.getElementById("content-display");
  contentDisplay.innerHTML = content;
}
<button onclick="navigate()">Click it</button>
<div id="content-display"></div>




Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472927/add-content-to-a-new-open-window

Yes, it's possible, but only when the page in the pop-up comes from the same domain as the retrieving page.

No, it is not possible.
When you open a new page, you do not control js on that page from an original page (given they are not from the same domain).
Js to control the new page has to be included in it.
Check possible parameters on MDN.

No. It is not possible unless the page is in the same domain as the retrieving page. Instead, you could use an iframe's srcdoc attribute + Javascript fetch() to get the HTML of another page.
